# JQuery submit intervention doesn't add parameter required in Controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have 4 submit buttons on my View and in order for them to call the right method in the controller I added a JQuery POST function.

Dependant on what buttons I click in the View I want the Controller to calculate whatever operation was selected. The JQuery correctly links my View with the Controller (the debugger first stops in the JQuery, then in the controller), however it doesn't seem to pass the parameter operation (needed in *CalculationValidation(Model, String)* ). So it ends up reloading the View with a new Model *(operation == null)*. What it should do is calculate the result dependant on the clicked operation and then reload the PartialView.

The JQuery does serialize the model correctly as the Model's properties Number1 and Number2 are filled from the View, but without the operation type. WIthout that I'm unable to calculate the result in the controller and load the PartialView with the updated model.

**Question / Goal**

How would I be able to load the PartialView with the Model.Result without reloading the full page after clicking the submit buttons?

***Prehaps important:*** The result of filling in the input fields and then clicking a submit button returns the error alert from the JQuery script.

**CalculationValidation.cshtml**

```
@using MVCPluginTest.Models
@model MVCPluginTest.Models.CalculatorModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Validation master Page";
}

<div id="containter">
    <h2>Validation</h2>
    @*@using (Html.BeginForm("CalculationValidation", "Home", FormMethod.Post))*@
    @*@using (Html.BeginForm("CalculationValidation", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "ValidationForm" , name = "ValidationForm"} ))*@
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CalculationValidation", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { id = "ValidationForm", name = "ValidationForm" }))
    {
        <!--
        if (@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            <b>
                Number 1 : @ViewBag.Number1<br />
                Number 2 : @ViewBag.Number2<br />
                Result: @ViewBag.Result
            </b>
        } -->
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <p>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number1)</p>
            <p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Number1) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Number1)</p>

            <p>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number2)</p>
            <p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Number2) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Number2)</p>
        </fieldset>
            <p><input type="submit" value="+" name="operation" id="btn-plus" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="-" name="operation" id="btn-minus" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="*" name="operation" id="btn-multiply" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="/" name="operation" id="btn-divide" /></p>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OperationType)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Result)

    }
</div>
<div id="dvCalculationResult">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("CalculationPartial", @Model); }
</div>
```

**LoadPartialCalc.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ValidationForm").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            //url: '@Url.Action("CalculationValidation", "Home")',
            url: "/Home/CalculationValidation",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $("#ValidationForm").serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#dvCalculationResult").html(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert("err");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**HomeController**

```
public ActionResult CalculationValidation()
{
    return View(new CalculatorModel());
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CalculationValidation(CalculatorModel valModel, string operation)
{
    var num1 = valModel.Number1;
    var num2 = valModel.Number2;
    if (operation == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("OperationType", "No operation type selected");
        return View(new CalculatorModel());
    }
    else
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            switch (operation)
            {
                case "+":
                    valModel.Result = num1 + num2;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    if (ValidateNumbers(num1, num2, "-"))
                    {
                        valModel.Result = num1 - num2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        valModel.Result = 0;
                        ModelState.AddModelError("Result", "Minus can't be lower than 0");
                    }
                    break;
                case "*":
                    valModel.Result = num1 * num2;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    if (ValidateNumbers(num1, num2, "/"))
                    {
                        valModel.Result = num1 / num2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        valModel.Result = 0;
                        ModelState.AddModelError("Result", "Division not whole.");
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    valModel.Result = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    valModel.Result = num1 + num2;
    return PartialView("CalculationPartial", valModel);
}
```

**CalculatorModel**

```
public class CalculatorModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a number.")]
    [Display(Name = "Number 1")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "You can only enter numbers above 0.")]
    public double Number1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a number.")]
    [Display(Name = "Number 2")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "You can only enter numbers above 0.")]
    public double Number2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string OperationType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public double Result
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

**CalculationPartial**

```
@using MVCPluginTest.Models
@model MVCPluginTest.Models.CalculatorModel

<h2>Result</h2>
<p id="result">@Model.Result</p>
```

Comment: You cancelling the standard submit so the buttons value will not be sent (`serialize()` will not include the value of the clicked button) One option would be to add the value of the clicked button using the `$.param()` function. Note also your last 2 `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` are pointless and can be removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only update (refresh) PartialView after submit click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617871/only-update-refresh-partialview-after-submit-click)

Comment: That makes alot of sense. How would I fix this though? I tried adding a parameter to the data property like the following: `data: $("#ValidationForm").serialize() + "&operation=" + "+"` However this gave me "/-/-" or something as a value for the operation parameter in the controller.

Comment: You can handle the buttons `.click()` event so you can get its value and then `var data = $("#ValidationForm").serialize()+ '&' + $.param({ operation : $(this).val() }, true);`. But you would be far better off having a radio button for each operation and one submit button (but why in the world would you do this in the controller instead of the view)?

Comment: Where and how do I add the value to the button with $.param. I've been trying and searching but I can't seem to make it work. I made it work with adding the attributes back after event.preventDefault(). Now my code runs again however I now only see the partial view.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by changing the JQuery parameter `dataType:"JSON"` to `contentType:"application/JSON"` and then I used `JSON.stringify(data)` in the data parameter. This updated the partial view without reloading the entire page.